# If $A$ is closed in $X\times X$ and $p$ is an open map, then $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$.
Let $A=\{(x, y)\in X\times X\mid x\sim y\}\subseteq X\times X$. Prove:

Let $p:X\to X/\sim$ denote the canonical projection.  If $A$ is closed in $X\times X$ and $p$ is an open map, then $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

Take $p(x), p(y) \in X / \sim$ distinct, so that $(x, y) \in (X \times X) - A$. Because $A$ is closed, we can find an open neighborhood of $(x, y)$ of the form $U \times V$, disjoint from $A$. Then $p(U)$ and $p(V)$ are disjoint open neighborhoods of $p(x)$ and $p(y)$.

Comment: How Can i by that conclude that X/~ is  Hausdorff?

Comment: By showing that any two points admit disjoint open neighborhoods